# How I can make "Time" to be update constantly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am beginner game dev in unity and i start new little project "alone", and in my game i have a little problem.

My problem is that the time, i.e. the clock in the game is not synchronized and does not synchronize and I have some suspicions.

I know maybe I'm doing another wrong step, maybe I put a wrong equation in the whole function and nothing works anymore, but to tell you more briefly, I want to make a game in which the game interface is a desktop and the clock on I coded it below, it doesn't work to be updated with time, I waited and tried many solutions that I applied and they didn't work, so I'll leave the code below

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;

public class DateTime : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Text timeLockScreenText;
    public Text dateLockScreenText;
    public Text timeTaskBarText;
    string time = System.DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime().ToString("HH:mm");
    string date = System.DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime().ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        InvokeRepeating("DateTimeV",0f,1f);
    }

    public void DateTimeV()
    {
    timeLockScreenText.text = time;
    dateLockScreenText.text = date;
    timeTaskBarText.text = timeLockScreenText.text;
    }
}
```

Now I have some theories:

- one is that in the game, just like in real life, it's like with any personal computer user when we open it there is a lockscreen with a clock and we press enter to enter all the time to access the internet and other files on the desktop, so I have the theory that the lockscreen being a GameObject which is like visibility opposite to the desktop, i.e. if the lockscreen is active the desktop is not visible and vice versa, the clock does not update because let's say if we are on the desktop the lockscreen is disabled and that's why the script doesn't really work and you have to to make two separate ones, one for the lockscreen and one for the desktop, actually for the clock on the desktop
- or I don't know how to code well

I tried to put in Update() function, in InvokeRepeting, StartCourutine with IEnumerator function, and i dont have the solutions

Comment: In general `DateTime` is a pretty expensive type to be used every frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use fixed update, and the code from `Rufus L`:

```
void FixedUpdate() => DateTimeV();

public void DateTimeV()
{
    DateTime utcNow = System.DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime();

    timeLockScreenText.text = utcNow.ToString("HH:mm");
    dateLockScreenText.text = utcNow.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
    timeTaskBarText.text = timeLockScreenText.text;
}
```

Comment: why the physics loop?

Comment: @derHugo, Less computationally expensive than regular Update.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! It helped me to solve my problem @CorrieJanse

Comment: well, yes but you could as well go back to OP's original intention and only update [once a second](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74804574/7111561) which would be even less computational expensive ;)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about Unity, but it seems that you're never updating the values of `time` and `date` after they're initially assigned. Perhaps something like this would do the trick, where you just assign the correct values in the method:

```
public void DateTimeV()
{
    DateTime utcNow = System.DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime();

    timeLockScreenText.text = utcNow.ToString("HH:mm");
    dateLockScreenText.text = utcNow.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
    timeTaskBarText.text = timeLockScreenText.text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What [Rufus L](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74803624/7111561) said + you would use `InvokeRepeating` only **once** e.g. in

```
private void Start()
{
    InvokeRepeating(nameof(DateTimeV), 0f, 1f);
}
```

or use a simple counter

```
private float timer;

private void Update ()
{
    timer += Time.deltaTime;

    if(timer > 1f)
    {
        timer -= 1f;

        DateTimeV();
    }
}
```

or a coroutine

```
private IEnumerator Start()
{
    while(true)
    {
        DateTimeV();

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
    }
}
```